# Open a socket using CreateFile

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, serial-port, createfile

We've got some old serial code which checks whether a serial port is available simply by opening it and then closing it. Now we are adding network support to the app I want to reuse the function by supplying the ip address as a string.

```
/**
 * So far I have tried:
 * A passed in portPath normally looks like:
\\?\acpi#pnp0501#1#1#{GUID}          
10.2.0.155:2001
//10.2.0.155:2001/
\\.\10.2.0.155:2001\
\\?\10.2.0.155:2001\
 * all without success.
 */
    bool PortIsAvailable( const CString& portPath )
    {
        HANDLE hCom = ::CreateFile( portPath,
                                   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                                   0,                    // comm devices must be opened with exclusive-access
                                   NULL,                 // no security attributes
                                   OPEN_EXISTING,        // comm devices must use OPEN_EXISTING
                                   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // not overlapped I/O
                                   NULL );                // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
        if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hCom ) 
        {
            ::CloseHandle( hCom );
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I know I could use connect followed by shutdown but I want to reuse the function with minimal changes. If I can reuse the function so much the better. If not then I will have to write code that determines whether it is a socket or not.

**I was wondering what the correct way of opening a socket via CreateFile is?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not create a socket via CreateFile. You should use the windows [socket API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741394(VS.85).aspx) for this purpose. For creating the SOCKET handle, you use [WSASocket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742212(VS.85).aspx). Note that the SOCKET returned by this function can be used as a Windows Handle with some [Windows functions, such as ReadFile and WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740522(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I knew you could use ReadFile and WriteFile, but I was thinking you could use CreateFile as well. It appears I will have to write all the extra boilerplate code to get around the fact that the system is built around serial ports:-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can manipulate sockets with `CreateFile()`. Sockets are an abstraction imported from BSD (iirc) and implemented in a name-compatible way (originally via `winsock.h`, and currently `winsock2.h`). I don't think MS ever added support for sockets to `CreateFile()`.

More rationale: Most (everything?) `CreateFile()` manipulates returns a native Windows handle. Because sockets are a non-native abstraction, they don't have a native handle in the OS, so it wouldn't make sense for `CreateFile()` to handle them.